# How to display dynamic columns for a simple MySQL 1 to many table?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm new to the concept of dynamic pivot tables in MySQL

This is my schema

**Table Article**

|| article_id | article_name ||

---

**Table Interest**
|| interest_id | interest_name ||

---

**Table Article_Interest_relation**

||article_id | interest_id ||

---

I'd like to fetch all articles like this

Article -> Interest 1 -> Interest 2 -> Interest 3 ..... Interest 'N'

```
|| Ipad | technology | science | engineering |..... | Interest 'N' ||
```

How can i create dynamic columns (depending on the number of interests) and fetch?

I'd like to do this using pivot tables?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you really need a *pivot* solution for this.
But, you can use `group_concat` while using `join`, for an appropriate solution.

```
select a.article_id
     , group_concat( i.interest_name ) as interests
  from articles a
  join article_interest_relation air on a.article_id=air.article_id
  join interests i on i.interest_id=air.interest_id 
 group by a.article_id
```

Comment: I can't have everything concatenated into 1 field,  The Question requires a dynamic number of columns

Comment: @wolfgang: Is there a limit for number of interests? For dynamic number of interests, we need a prepared sql statement.